# Can I dilute 2-stroke gas and run it in my riding mower to get rid of it?

Tags: gasoline, lawnmower, two-stroke

Over the winter I needed a chainsaw, I mixed a gallon of gas for it and unfortunately it just refused to start which gave me the motivation to purchase an electric chainsaw which did the job wonderfully.

Problem is, now I have a gallon of two-stroke gas that I just don't know what to do with. I'd like to just dilute it into the 5-gallon can I use for my mower and use it over the summer, but before I do that I figured I'd ask if there's any reason I shouldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to run this straight through your lawnmower without issue. As long as you aren't running it through your car with a catalytic converter it should be just fine. The thing which 2-cycle oil has in it is lubricants. Today's mixes burn very clean. Doesn't mean you *can't cut it* with regular fuel, just it's not going to hurt anything running it straight.

If you haven't done so, you'll probably want to put some Stabil or other type of fuel stabilizer in it so it won't continue collecting water via whatever amount of ethanol it might have in it. I use it in any type of fuel which is going to be sitting for any amount of time. You can treat gas so it will be in good shape for up to two years. Not an advertisement, just a consideration.

Comment: Well I'm glad I didn't listen to my uncle who's trees I cut down; he said to put it in my car for the trip home -- thing is he drives a 1970s f150, I drive a 2017 edge. His truck probably would have been fine, mine probably not.

Comment: @Sidney - It *might* even be fine in your car. I just wouldn't like the idea of whatever is in the exhaust ruining the cat ***BECAUSE*** ... lol :o) Just not a good idea in my book.

Comment: On top of that my mower is only a couple of grand and I'm certain a local shop can fix anything for less than that -- My car is still 5 figures if I screw that up and can't imagine what a shop would charge for a fix

Comment: @Sidney on a mower it'll be the ... spark plug.  On a car it'll be the ... catalytic converter.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - If your theory were true, wouldn't that happen to *any* spark plug? I'm thinking 2-stroke engines have spark plugs, too, yet, they don't foul out, do they?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm talking about worst case really.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - You're right, that would be worst case. It's just "that" worst case could happen with any petrol engine using any type of gasoline at any given time. By writing what I wrote, I'm trying to let the OP know it is no more of a concern than it is at any other time, which is absolutely correct.

Comment: Oh... I'm not trying to call you wrong.  Just illustrating that the worst case mower damage is $9 and the car $900.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Fair enough. TY for clarifying.

Answer (score 11):

As long as you dilute it there should be no issues. Mixing a gallon or so with 5 gallons takes a 50:1 fuel-to-oil ratio to about 250:1.  In other words, the engine will never notice it.

Comment: +1 I do this all the time, adding up to 1/3 of 50:1 to 2/3 regular gasoline for a riding mower. The spark plug stays clean and it doesn't create visible smoke, so no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

yea without a problem man, in fact the engine will kind of enjoy the extra little bit of lubricity in spots it doesnt usually get it, not somethin u want to do all the time in something not designed for it because of buildup, but youll b fine in ur case especially diluted with 4 other fresh gallons  the worst thing youll have to worry about is buildup on ur spark plug, but i doubt youll even notice a difference